System.AggregateException: "Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor Data.interfaces.IAllOrders
I really need help. An error occurred when launching the application:

System.AggregateException: "Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: kursov.Data.interfaces.IAllOrders Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: kursov.Data.Repository.OrdersRepository': Unable to resolve service for type 'kursov.Models.ShoppingCart' while attempting to activate 'kursov.Data.Repository.OrdersRepository'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: kursov.Controllers.OrderController Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: kursov.Controllers.OrderController': Unable to resolve service for type 'kursov.Models.ShoppingCart' while attempting to activate 'kursov.Data.Repository.OrdersRepository'.)

I don't understand what needs to be added to the Startup, please help.
ConfigureServices in Startup:
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
     options.UseSqlServer(
         Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
         .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
         .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
         .AddDefaultUI();
services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();
services.AddSingleton<IFileProvider>(
         new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot/Uploads")));
      
services.AddScoped<IFileService, FileService>();
 
services.AddTransient<IAllMedicaments, MedicamentRepository>();
services.AddTransient<IMedicamentsCategory, CategoryRepository>();
services.AddTransient<IAllApteks, AptekRepository>();
services.AddTransient<IAllOrders, OrdersRepository>();

ApplicationDbContext:
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Addresses> Addresses { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Apteks> Apteks { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Medicaments> Medicaments { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ShoppingCartItem> ShoppingCartItem { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ShoppingCart> ShoppingCart { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Order> Order { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<OrderDetail> OrderDetail { get; set; }
}

OrdersRepository:
public class OrdersRepository : IAllOrders
{
     private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
     private readonly ShoppingCart _shoppingCart;

     public OrdersRepository(ApplicationDbContext context, ShoppingCart shoppingCart)
     {
         this._context = context;
         this._shoppingCart = shoppingCart;
     }

     public void createOrder(Order order)
     {
         order.orderTime = DateTime.Now;
         _context.Order.Add(order);
         _context.SaveChanges();
         var items = _shoppingCart.ShoppingCartItems;

         foreach (var el in items)
         {
             var orderDetail = new OrderDetail()
             {
                 orderID = order.id,
                 MedicamentID = el.Medicaments.MedicamentsId,
                 price = el.Medicaments.MedicamentPrice
             };
             
             _context.OrderDetail.Add(orderDetail);
         }
         _context.SaveChanges();
     }
}

IAllOrders:
public interface IAllOrders
{
    void createOrder(Order order);
}

ShoppingCart:
public class ShoppingCart
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    [Key]
    public string CartId { get; set; }
    //  public string ShoppingCartId { get; set; }
    public List<ShoppingCartItem> ShoppingCartItems { get; set; } 

    private ShoppingCart(ApplicationDbContext context, string cartId)
    {
        _context = context;
        CartId = cartId;
        ShoppingCartItems = new List<ShoppingCartItem>();
    }

    public static async Task<ShoppingCart> GetCart(ApplicationDbContext context, string cartId)
    {
        // Реализация метода GetCart, как показано выше...
        var cart = await context.ShoppingCart
                            .Include(c => c.ShoppingCartItems)
                                .ThenInclude(sci => sci.Medicaments)
                            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(c => c.CartId == cartId);

        if (cart == null)
        {
            cart = new ShoppingCart(context, cartId);
            context.ShoppingCart.Add(cart);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        return cart;
    }

    public void AddToCart(Medicaments product, int quantity)
    {
        var cartItem = _context.ShoppingCartItem.SingleOrDefault(
            c => c.Medicaments.MedicamentsId == product.MedicamentsId && c.ShoppingCartId == CartId);

        if (cartItem == null)
        {
            cartItem = new ShoppingCartItem
            {
                ShoppingCartId = CartId,
                Medicaments = product,
                Quantity = quantity
            };

            _context.ShoppingCartItem.Add(cartItem);
        }
        else
        {
            cartItem.Quantity += quantity;
        }

        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void RemoveFromCart(Medicaments product)
    {
        var cartItem = _context.ShoppingCartItem.SingleOrDefault(
            c => c.Medicaments.MedicamentsId == product.MedicamentsId && c.ShoppingCartId == CartId);

        if (cartItem != null)
        {
            if (cartItem.Quantity > 1)
            {
                // Если количество больше одного, уменьшаем количество
                cartItem.Quantity--;
            }
            else
            {
                // Если товар в количестве одной штуки, удаляем его из корзины
                _context.ShoppingCartItem.Remove(cartItem);
            }

            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    public void ClearCart()
    {
        ShoppingCartItems.Clear();
    }

    public decimal GetTotal()
    {
        return ShoppingCartItems.Sum(item => item.Medicaments.MedicamentPrice * item.Quantity);
    }

    public List<ShoppingCartItem> getShopItems()
    {
        return _context.ShoppingCartItem.Where(c => c.ShoppingCartId == CartId).Include(s => s.Medicaments).ToList();
    }
}

